# Redundant conformance of the ChatViewController to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error:

> Redundant conformance of the ChatViewController to protocol

This is my code:

```
class ChatViewController: ViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

How can I fix?

Comment: What is `ViewController` ? Is it some sort of a base class or you just meant `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this means that your ViewController class already implements UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource.